# How to mock super method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I extended a method and am trying to test the child method, but there is a call to the overridden method that I can't figure out how to mock.

```
public class Parent()
{
    public String foo()
    {
        //Various checks and validation

        if(successful)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}

public class Child()
{
    boolean someVariableSetElseWhere;

    @Override
    public String foo()
    {
        String error = super.foo();

        if(error == null && someVariableSetElseWhere)
        {
            //do some other checks
            error = bar();
        }

        return error;
    }
}
```

I want to check whether `bar()` is called when `someVariableSetElseWhere` is in different states, but I'm always getting `"error"` from `super.foo()`, so the if statement is always false. Is there a way to mock the super class to return null.

I tried

```
Child mock = Mockito.mock(Child.class);
Mockito.when((Parent)mock.foo()).thenReturn(null);
```

in my test, but Child.foo() returned null every time

Comment: Your example should make clear that `Child extends Parent` and maybe it would help to correct the syntax of your class definition. Besides, mocking a super call is a bad idea. If the result of the overriden method should depend on super, than test it in an integrated way (otherwise you test the mock, not your code). If the result of the overriden method should not depend on super, than do not call super and duplicate the code from the super method. In both cases you will not need a mock.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `mock()` with the code under test, you use `spy()` with a concrete instace:

Child cut = Mockito.spy(new Child());

But this will **not** work for a method overridden in the `Child` class since `spy()` simply wraps the cut and intercepts the method call using regular *polymorphism*.

## Do not mock or spy your Code under test

1. UnitTest verify *public observable behavior* of a unit, and since `Child` extends `Parent` I'd consider them being a "unit" all together. In that case the call of `super.foo()` is an *implementation detail* you should not be tested.
2. If you consider  `Child` and `Parent` being individual units you should also consider  to apply *Favor Composition over Inheritance* and inject an instance ob `Parent` into `Child` (preferably via *constructor parameter*) instead of having `Child` extending `Parent`. This makes it way easier to replace `Parent` with a test double.

Comment: Using `spy` will not enable testing a super call. `when(cut.foo())` will not change the result of `Parent.foo` but the result of `Child.foo`. I agree with your other recommendations.